# on backpress() with finish() causes IllegalStateException in android

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

on backpress() with finish() causes  IllegalStateException in android

I am using Firebase to track error and this error has been shown for the first time 
the activity doesnot even have  fragment

the code is  just simple

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
```

the firebase details are

```
Android API: 23
Android OS: 6.0.1
```

`IllegalStateException - FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss`

and the error details are

```
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss (FragmentManager.java:1413)
android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate (FragmentManager.java:576)
android.app.Activity.onBackPressed (Activity.java:2520)
com.Quest.Activity.onBackPressed (PlayerActivity.java:409)
android.app.Activity.onKeyUp (Activity.java:2494)
android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch (KeyEvent.java:2676)
android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent (Activity.java:2751)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2310)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4159)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:4121)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3722)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3688)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3814)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3696)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3871)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3722)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3688)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:3696)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:3722)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3688)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:3847)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:4013)
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run (InputMethodManager.java:2272)
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback (InputMethodManager.java:1893)
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent (InputMethodManager.java:1884)
android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished (InputMethodManager.java:2249)
android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished (InputEventSender.java:141)
android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5441)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:738)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: either remove `super.onBackpress()` from your code or write `finish()` after `super.onBackpress()`

Comment: where are you implementing `onBackpressed`...fragment ?